# Why is this .push() not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var rangesliderfilter = function () {
    var low = parseInt(jQuery('#min-value-span').text());
    var high = parseInt(jQuery('#max-value-span').text());
    var BreakfastDR = [];
    var LunchDR = [];
    var DinnerDR = [];
    var SnacksDR = [];
    while (low <= high) {
        BreakfastDR.push('.' + low++ +'.breakfast');
        LunchDR.push('.' + low++ +'.lunch');
        DinnerDR.push('.' + low++ +'.dinner');
        SnacksDR.push('.' + low++ +'.snacks');
        }

    jQuery('.rangecheck').attr('value', BreakfastDR);
}
```

This is adding the value in intervals of 4. So if low is 0 and high is 16 the string added is: `.0.breakfast,.4.breakfast,.8.breakfast,.12.breakfast`

It should be doing every number this way not just in intervals of 4. `.0.breakfast,.1.breakfast,.2.breakfast,etc`

anyone see an obvious reason why? Should I not be pushing into different vars in the same `while function`??

Comment: You're incrementing `low` four times every loop iteration, so it will increment by four. Increment it once.

Comment: `++` is a shortcut operator that increments the value by 1. There are similar shortcuts such as `--`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you are incrementing `low` four times in your loop. Only increment it once at the end:

```
while (low <= high) {
    BreakfastDR.push('.' + low +'.breakfast');
    LunchDR.push('.' + low +'.lunch');
    DinnerDR.push('.' + low +'.dinner');
    SnacksDR.push('.' + low +'.snacks');
    low++;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, never used it before. It works Thanks. I'll accept when it lets me

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're incrementing `low` *four* times with the following code, once after each meal type:

```
BreakfastDR.push('.' + low++ +'.breakfast');  // Use 0, set to 1.
LunchDR.push('.' + low++ +'.lunch');          // Use 1, set to 2.
DinnerDR.push('.' + low++ +'.dinner');        // Use 2, set to 3.
SnacksDR.push('.' + low++ +'.snacks');        // Use 3, set to 4.
```

So breakfast will get `0`, lunch will get `1` and so on. The next breakfast after the initial one will get `4`. You'll end up with:

```
breakfast   0,  4,  8, 12, 16, ...
lunch       1,  5,  9, 13, 17, ...
dinner      2,  6, 10, 14, 18, ...
snacks      3,  9, 11, 15, 19, ...
```

Assuming you want *each* of your meal types to get the sequence `0, 1, 2, ...`, you should use something like:

```
BreakfastDR.push('.' + low +'.breakfast');
LunchDR.push('.' + low +'.lunch');
DinnerDR.push('.' + low +'.dinner');
SnacksDR.push('.' + low++ +'.snacks');
```

or, if you may want to add meals after snacks at some point:

```
BreakfastDR.push('.' + low +'.breakfast');
LunchDR.push('.' + low +'.lunch');
DinnerDR.push('.' + low +'.dinner');
SnacksDR.push('.' + low +'.snacks');
low++;
```